# FaceAware Imageview in Android

Tags: android, imageview, face-detection, scaletype

I am looking for face Aware Image-view. Instead of cropping Image or simply center crop scale type of Image-view, the face should detect in image-view and adjust face to center of Image-view. Is there any Android Custom Image-view library  provide such functionality?

**I looked at below references but not got success.**

https://medium.com/@ayltai/youre-cropping-images-wrong-a79e8f67e6c9

**I got Library in IOS but not getting anything in Android.**

https://github.com/BeauNouvelle/FaceAware

Can anyone help me out? Thank You.

Comment: refer this [link](https://github.com/aryarohit07/PicassoFaceDetectionTransformation) may helps you

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have seen that link. But actually, it detect face and cropped image to make it center. Can I achieve this without cropping any image?

Comment: Without Cropping it is not possible with this library. I think your requirement is satisfied with this library @sanket Thakare

Comment: Thanks for reply. Crop is not in my requirement. so, will look for other option and update if find something.